# Should develop iOS app with WebDevelopment Tool or xCode

Tags: c#, android, ios, xcode

I have studied web development using Visual Studio C# for quite awhile. Right now I want to develop a Mobile App which shows a gallery of images, and also a search bar to search image.

I have two way of developing the App in my mind

First Way: Develop the web page using C# and make it mobile responsive, then in xCode use web view which I embed a browser in the app

Second way: Develope the app in xCode

I have tried different apps. apps that embbed browser do not seem to be as good as the one that directly coded in the mobile develop tool, because when you open a page there is the refresh, back button on the bottom. But by using the first method, I can easily develop an android version since xCode is only for iOS development

So..I'm asking which way is better and what are the differences between these two way

Comment: Third way is to use Xamarin (http://www.xamarin.com). Will be able to re-use your C# and build the same app for other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitly sounds like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/?_bt=44014802708&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=CjwKEAiAqrqkBRCep-rKnt_r_lkSJAArVUBcjWXizR7iYOP1bJn4ghHxAgR4dbl9ywgi9w2bsncx9RoCP_jw_wcB) is the perfect fit for you, it uses C# and can develop for both Android & IOS.